# How to display and count entities from an object array from a json using angularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I want want to display and count only batter in batters at index `0`.

i.e  `id = 1001` `type = regular`

and count should be "4"

Comment: here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8u0zwwud/

Answer (score 0):

Use array filter method..

```
var getBatter1001 = (item) => { return item.batters.batter.filter((x) => {x.id === '1001'}); } 
var batter1001 = $scope.myData.filter(getBatter1001);

console.log('Count of objects with batter id 1001: '+batter1001.length); // Logs 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/8u0zwwud/3/) updated JSFiddle will give you an idea.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="x in myData">
    <li ng-repeat = "batter in x.batters.batter | filter: {'id': 1001, 'type': 'Regular'}">
      {{ batter.id }} - {{ batter.type }}
    </li>
  </ul>

  {{countBatters(1001, 'Regular')}}
</div>
```

Added function in controller:

```
$scope.countBatters = function(id, type) {
    return $scope.myData.filter(function(obj) {
       var batter = obj.batters.batter[0];
       return batter.id == id && batter.type == type
    }).length;
}
```

Comment: this displays first id and type of every batter but say I need only from 1st batter with id=0001